# Best approach to determine Oracle INSERT or UPDATE using NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JSON flow-file and I need determine if I should be doing an INSERT or UPDATE. The trick is to only update the columns that match the JSON attributes. I have an ExecuteSQL working and it returns executesql.row.count, however I've lose the original JSON flow-file which I was planing to use as a routeonattribute. I'm trying to get the MergeContent to join the ExecuteSQL (dump the Avro output, I only need the executesql.row.count attribute) with the JSON flow. I've set follow before I do the ExecuteSQL:

fragment.count=2

fragment.identifier=${UUID()}

fragment.index=${nextInt()}

Alternatively I could create a MERGE, if there is a way to loop through the list of JSON attributes that match the Oracle table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How large is your JSON? If it's small, you might consider using ExtractText (matching the whole document) to get the JSON into an attribute. Then you can run ExecuteSQL, then ReplaceText to put the JSON back into the content (overwriting the Avro results). If your JSON is large, you could set up a [DistributedMapCacheServer](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.server.map.DistributedMapCacheServer/index.html) and (in a separate flow) run ExecuteSQL and store the value or executesql.row.count into the cache. Then in the JSON flow you can use [FetchDistributedMapCache](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchDistributedMapCache/index.html) with the "Put Cache Value In Attribute" property set.

If you only need the JSON to use RouteOnAttribute, perhaps you could use [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) before ExecuteSQL, so your conditions are already in attributes and you can replace the flow file contents.

If you want to use MergeContent, you can set fragment.count to 2, but rather than using the UUID() function, you could set "parent.identifier" to "${uuid}" using UpdateAttribute, then [DuplicateFlowFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.DuplicateFlowFile/index.html) to create 2 copies, then UpdateAttribute to set "fragment.identifier" to "${parent.identifier}" and "fragment.index" to "${nextInt():mod(2)}". This gives a mergeable set of two flow files, you can route on fragment.index being 0 or 1, sending one to ExecuteSQL and one through the other flow, joining back up at MergeContent.

Another alternative is to use [ConvertJSONToSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html) set to "UPDATE", and if it fails, route those flow files to another ConvertJSONToSQL processor set to "INSERT".

Comment: I've used your approach to Store the JSON in an Attribute. Works like a charm, thank you